# 検索エンジンを実装するにあたり、「とう」や「tok」、「東」というインプットから「東京」という結果をサジェストして欲しい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, aws, elasticsearch

下記を実現するにはどうやるのがよいでしょうか？
自分なりに考えた実現方法案も後述しましたので、それらも参考にしていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

### やりたいこと

APIのパラメーターで文字列を渡す。それをキーにテキストリストから検索をしたい。
具体的には、「とう」や「tok」、「東」というインプットにたいして、
後述の都道府県リストから「東京」という結果を取得したい。
「とう」のときに「糖分」がひっかかるのはOK

単語リスト

東京
京都
大阪
北海道
福岡
糖分

※ 文章ではなくて、すでに単語レベルにパースされてるという前提で大丈夫です
※ レコード数は多くても数百(パフォーマンスは問題にならないかと）

### 環境

Rails 4.2.6
AWS EC2 + RDS for MYSQL 5.7

### 実現方法案

1. 普通にMySQLでlike検索
   「東」と入力しないとひっかからない
   平仮名、アルファベットのカラムを用意してそこからもlike検索をすれば、
   平仮名でもアルファベットでもOK?
   ※ レコード数は多くないので、速度は気にしません。
   ※ kakasiが使えそう
2. MySQL5.7でのfull-text index
   1と同様で、平仮名、アルファベット、漢字のそれぞれの転置インデックスを作らないとダメ。
   ※ 参考までに、RDSではNグラムパーサーしか使えません。
3. Elastic search
   いれるのが大変そう(試してない）。今回はそこまでコストかけずに実装したい
   Kuromojiをいれれば、漢字と読みの紐付けはできる
4. 他になにかあれば

#### その他

googleだと検索する時に「とうky」などといれても東京がサジェストされるのですが、
いったい彼らはどうやって実装してるんですかね。。。

Comment: 自分がこの要件で実装するのだとしたら、 Elasticsearch を用いると思います。具体的に動いている例は、、仰る通り、ちょっと面倒なので、一旦コメントで。。

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch を使い、ローマ字読みの field を用意して前方一致で解決するのが良いかな……と思います。正規化のために適宜マッピング等も利用すると思います。

実際の実装は少し長くなるので、同様のことをしているブログ記事をいくつか置いておきます。

- [Elasticsearch キーワードサジェスト日本語のための設計](https://medium.com/hello-elasticsearch/elasticsearch-%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%B5%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E8%A8%88-352a230030dd) -- Hello! Elasticsearch
- [日本語でのサジェストの難しさとElasticsearchを用いた実装例](http://techblog.housmart.co.jp/2016/12/16/suggester-for-japanese/) -- カウル Tech Blog

Elasticsearch でなくて Solr を使う例も見つけたのでこちらもリンクを置いておきます。

- [Solrを用いて検索のサジェスターを作りました](https://techblog.zozo.com/entry/solr-suggester) -- ZOZO Technologies TECH BLOG